# Merging multiple intersecting/overlapping polygons in QGIS

Tags: qgis, merge, overlapping-features, dissolve, polygon-creation

Is there a way in QGIS to select multiple polygons and merge only the ones that intersect/overlap with each other? As in the example bellow only those appointed would merge, becoming each a single feature.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Dissolve
2. Multipart to Singleparts